# Is running a privileged docker and mounting / considered safe?

Tags: docker

I want to add a dashboard to my server, and I was looking for lighter solutions than Grafana + Prometheus.

I found something that looks great and extremely light, but there is one thing that makes me ask if it is as good solution. The docker-compose is as follow :

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  ****:
    image: ****
    privileged: true
    volumes:
      - /:/mnt/host:ro
```

It runs as privileged, and it mount the whole disk (/). I'm planning to add it to the same docker network than some other apps.

Knowing that it will be only accessible with https and basic auth, what do I risk and what can I do to counter that?

Comment: It needs to mount the _entire_ host filesystem, and run as a privileged container?  That's far more permissions than a dashboarding solution needs.  Find or build something else that's not going to risk compromising your host.

Comment: ("Is it considered safe?"  No, both of those things are giant red flags.)